# make grouping bar plot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot2 but trying to use it. I have two variables: SA( with 4 levels :0, 1000,2000 and 3000) and GA (with 4 levels:0, 0.5,1 and 2). I would like to group these by SA (like this Figure)
[image]

```
> G<- read.table("k.csv", sep=";",header = TRUE)
> G
SA  GA PH
1     0 0.0 41
2     0 0.0 27
3     0 0.0 28
4     0 0.0 25
5     0 0.5 35
6     0 0.5 45
7     0 0.5 35
8     0 0.5 55
9     0 1.0 45
10    0 1.0 35
11    0 1.0 38
12    0 1.0 46
13    0 2.0 52
14    0 2.0 40
15    0 2.0 40
16    0 2.0 35
17 1000 0.0 30
18 1000 0.0 30
19 1000 0.0 30
20 1000 0.0 30
21 1000 0.5 28
22 1000 0.5 33
23 1000 0.5 31
24 1000 0.5 42
25 1000 1.0 38
26 1000 1.0 30
27 1000 1.0 27
28 1000 1.0 25
29 1000 2.0 30
30 1000 2.0 22
31 1000 2.0 31
32 1000 2.0 44
33 2000 0.0 18
34 2000 0.0 25
35 2000 0.0 24
36 2000 0.0 31
37 2000 0.5 24
38 2000 0.5 22
39 2000 0.5 36
40 2000 0.5 40
41 2000 1.0 27
42 2000 1.0 29
43 2000 1.0 42
44 2000 1.0 33
45 2000 2.0 20
46 2000 2.0 40
47 2000 2.0 30
48 2000 2.0 25
49 3000 0.0  0
50 3000 0.0  0
51 3000 0.0  0
52 3000 0.0  0
53 3000 0.5 24
54 3000 0.5 20
55 3000 0.5 25
56 3000 0.5 NA
57 3000 1.0 37
58 3000 1.0 NA
59 3000 1.0 38
60 3000 1.0 25
61 3000 2.0 24
62 3000 2.0 15
63 3000 2.0 20
64 3000 2.0 32
> ggplot(G, aes(x=SA, y=PH, fill=factor(GA))) +   
stat_summary(geom="bar",positiGon=position_dodge(1))
```

but it does not give me what I need. It gives me something different (here it is)
[image]

Also, I would like to add error bar to the bars.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution where I use `data.table` to calculate standard error and mean.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
setDT(G)
pd <- G[, .(SE = sd(PH, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(.N),
            MN = mean(PH, na.rm = TRUE)), 
           .(SA, GA)]
ggplot(pd, aes(factor(SA), fill = factor(GA))) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = MN), 
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = MN - SE, ymax = MN + SE),
                  position = "dodge") +
    labs(x = "SA",
         y = "PH",
         fill = "GA") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)

std.error <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
means <- function(x)mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)


df2 <- G %>% 
       group_by(SA, GA) %>% 
       mutate(error=std.error(PH)) %>% 
       summarise_at(vars(PH:error), funs(means))

ggplot(df2, aes(as.factor(SA), PH, fill=as.factor(GA))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=PH-error, ymax=PH+error), 
                  width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks  Adam ! however, it gives me an error with Error in group_by(., SA, GA) : could not find function "group_by"

Comment: `group_by` is a function from the `dplyr` package. You will have to load this package in order to use `group_by`.

Comment: try installing and loading the packages of "tidyverse", i.e. `install.packages("tidyverse"); library(tidyverse)`

Comment: I have installed and loaded both dplyr  and tidyverse but it is still the same error message.  > library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘bindr’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.4.2